# MVC3 Razor Html.TextBoxFor Calculated Fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Ultimately I would like to have calculated fields like Weight * Price.

Suppose I have in my MVC3 view:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Package.USDKg)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Pricing.VolumePrice)
```

Am I able to calculate these directly? Or resort to JQuery?
I would really like to keep pricing "hidden" even in source view if possible.

Basically, when a user enters their package weight, a price would be displayed (calculated off of hidden price point values).

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a razor, you could do a logic just inside the mark up!

```
@{
   var value = model.Item.Value;
   var price = model.Item.Proce;
   var calculated = value * price;
}

<div class="price>Your price: @calculated</div>
```

More info is here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Thank you!  That would be super but I am now facing "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable".
There's an essay here: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/03/17/lambda-inference but wondering if there had been any changes since then to make life easier.

Comment: @Par6 please carefully read the error message and check the place where it is pointing.. if think you would be able to fix that :) if no, please create new question.. if my answer helped you, please mark it as "correct"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do it like this:

```
function calculate(){
   var weight = parseFloat($("#Package_USDKg").val());
   var price = parseFloat($("#Pricing_VolumePrice").val());
   var calculus = weight * price;
   $("#calculus").text(calculus); //This shows the calculated field
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  calculate(); //Calculate on page load
  $("#Package_USDKg").change(calculate);  //Calculate every time weight changes
});
```

I'm assuming you have a div with `id="calculus"` to show the calculated field.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It is not higly preferable to use JS, then you could use Razor for that :)