# How to show a calculated field in an MVC Razor form?

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Starting out with MVC4 and Razor forms but having trouble showing a *calculated* field in the form - prior to **submitting** the form.

Say, for simplicity sake, we have fields Price and Quantity which are editable textboxes and a third readonly textbox to show the calculated total Price * Quantity.

This [post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633449/180430) it's nice and easy with our newfangled Razor but when we try the below absolutely nothing changes dynamically on the form:

```
@{
   var value = model.Item.Value;
   var price = model.Item.Proce;
   var calculated = value * price;
}

<div class="price">Your price: @calculated</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be real time as the user types or before submitting the form you're going to have to use javascript; server-side razor code will not be enough.  The razor code will only be executed when the page is first rendered.

You have a few options:

1. As the user is done typing send the data to the server via ajax to
   get a calculated total.  Take the response and display it on the
   page
2. Just update the calculation completely on the client as the user
   types (you could use a MVVM framework to help with this (e.g.
       Knockout.js))

**Edit**

Adding some links to examples:

Here is an example for #1: [Making a Simple Ajax call to controller in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Here is an example of how you could achieve #2:  http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Personally I would do the calculation on the client (#2) and just do your validation server-side since that's where it matters.

Comment: thanks, can you add any links with some starter guidelines for either of these?

Comment: Sure, I've added a few links.